# Data binding with string format in layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, data-binding

In my android app, I have a Seekbar that allows the user to select a radius. On moving the slider of the seekbar, I want a textview to display the current value of the seekbar.

In my fragment, I listen to seekbar changes and update my viewmodel accordingly. However, the value of radius in the textview doesn't change. While debugging, I noticed that my viewmodel `searchOffers.searchQuery` doesn't have any listeners attached. Does `android:text="@{@string/searchRadius(searchOffers.searchQuery.radiusInKm)}"` not add a listener to `searchQuery`?

I already set the textview string manually while listening to the seekbar changes, which works. But I don't understand why the other solution (which seems more elegant and readable) doesn't work. Does anybody know why or what an appropriate solution would be?

Note that I only included the relevant parts of the code. Using different parts of the viewmodel works.

My string to format is `<string name="searchRadius">Radius: %s km</string>`

My fragment_layout.xml:

```xml
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="searchOffers"
            type="com.example.SearchOffersViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/radius_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{@string/searchRadius(searchOffers.searchQuery.radiusInKm)}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/radius_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:max="30"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radius_text" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My ViewModel:

```kotlin
class SearchOffersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val searchQuery = MutableLiveData<ProductSearchQuery>()
}

class ProductSearchQuery {
    var radiusInKm: Int = 0
}
```

My Fragment:

```kotlin
class MyFragment() : Fragment(), OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SearchOffersViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLayoutBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SearchOffersViewModel::class.java)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
        binding.searchOffers = viewModel
        binding.radiusSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this)
        binding.radiusSeekbar.progress = viewModel.searchQuery.value!!.radiusInKm

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onProgressChanged(seekbar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        // I could update the text here manually and then do
        // binding.radius_text.text = resources.getString(R.string.searchRadius).format(progress)
        // viewModel.searchQuery.value!!.radiusInKm = progress
        
        val query = viewModel.searchQuery.value!!
        query.radiusInKm = progress
        viewModel.searchQuery.value = query
    }
}
```